# There's "\n" in my metadata that I get from calling API from own server

Tags: java, mysql, reactjs, spring-boot

Basically, after calling the API and rendering such data on my frontend and console-logging them, some of the data I get have extra "\n" at the end of the string. Yet, I didn't enter any "/n" in my java server. For description, imageUrl and SizeOne, I get an extra "\n", which I assume is due to my backend. Something that draws my attention is how some attributes have an extra arrow pointing at themselves while others don't and those with arrows happen to be the data with the extra "\n".
For your information, I only set size_one to be nullable, and for the rest, they are all not nullable, which I am not sure if is responsible for the issue.

[image: Below is the console log]

[image: Mysql database]

[image: The java entities]

Comment: a `\n` (incorrectly stated by you as `/n`) is a linebreak character. Your ide displays that character as that arrow (which should look like your Enter key on your keyboard). Fix your backend and make sure there is no garbage returned from it. If that is not an option, replace it inside the String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\n` means new line. As you can see in your DB there's a new line in the end.
ease hack would be trim that is javaScript in the client even tho that's not the "right way". (`yourString.replace("\n","")`)